# Re-writing this mysql Statement

Tags: mysql, join, case, inner-join

I am trying to add two fields from another table using join (inner or join) to this statement. How best can I write this?
I have added only the relevant table as requested [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4uzIxyf_WfVVXFoSFk4NnJXS1U)                                              Desired Result 
               `| a_l_code |   dr_cr_code_inc  |
                |----------|-------------------|
                |   FA     |      DR           |`

```
select B.joint_account_numbers,
    B.account_title,
    SUM(case when A.dr_cr_action = 'CR' then A.amount * - 1 else A.amount end) as net_reduction
from (
    select A.joint_account_number,
        A.dr_cr_action,
        A.amount
    from mainaccount_a_2017 A

    union all

    select B.joint_account_number,
        B.dr_cr_action,
        B.amount
    from mainaccount_b_2017 B
    ) as A
inner join chart_of_account B on A.joint_account_number = B.joint_account_numbers
group by B.joint_account_numbers;
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. What's the problem?

Comment: @GurV Yes, this is Ok, but my challenge is this. I have a table called **asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl** with these fields **a_l_code** and **dr_cr_code_inc**. How do I add this to the statement?

Comment: Add that where? what is the relationship with these tables? I suggest you provide some sample data and expected output explaining what you want in the result.

Comment: @AderogbaOtunla . . . You should ask another question and include references to the appropriate tables, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GurV  Sample data and screenshot [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4uzIxyf_WfVVXFoSFk4NnJXS1U)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sample data and screenshot [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4uzIxyf_WfVVXFoSFk4NnJXS1U)

Comment: @AderogbaOtunla - Please add the data as textual table in the question not links to other sites. Also, don't export the whole database. Add only the relevant tables.

Comment: @GurV I have added only the relevant table as requested [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4uzIxyf_WfVVXFoSFk4NnJXS1U)                                                        `|           a_l_code                       |               dr_cr_code_inc|
|---------------------------------------|--------------------------------|
|            FA                                |                  DR                  |` **Emm! I don't know how to do the textual table here**

Comment: @AderogbaOtunla - In the question please

Comment: Thanks @GurV figured it out!

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff figured it out!

Comment: @AderogbaOtunla - Good for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Figured it out!    

    select B.joint_account_numbers,
    B.account_title, C.a_l_code, C.dr_cr_code_inc,
    SUM(case when A.dr_cr_action = 'CR' then A.amount * - 1 else A.amount end) as net_reduction
    from (
    select A.joint_account_number,
        A.dr_cr_action,
        A.amount
    from mainaccount_a_2017 A

    union all

    select B.joint_account_number,
        B.dr_cr_action,
        B.amount
    from mainaccount_b_2017 B
    ) as A
    inner join chart_of_account B on A.joint_account_number = B.joint_account_numbers
    inner join asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl C on B.account_type = C.a_l_code
    group by B.joint_account_numbers;`
```